# Scrollable Modal where the X stays top left of the Modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Trying to make a Y scrollable modal. Its width is not set, it may be narrow on wide screens, or most of the screen width on small screens. I wish to have a X top right for closing the Modal, that even if the user scolls down a few pages of the modal (because the modal is long), they don't have to scoll back up to close the modal.

Because of the changing modal width one can't just simply say right: 123px, or 10%.

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <div>This modal is different widths.
    <br>Depending on the screen.
    <br>you view it on.
    <br>It may
    <br>get so long
    <br>you have to scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.ModalBlur {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #00000040;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.Modal {
  position: relative;
  background: white;  
  padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 124px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Current result:
[image]

Desired the X to be top right, something like below. Even if the modal is very long and one has to scroww Y.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just played with it. Link below.

Changed .Modal display to "block" and gave .close a position of "sticky", and need to give it a set margin to keep from the top.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTSNCGBVYIFD

Hope it works for your purposes :)

ps.: My example has the .Modal height set to 100px so that I could test the scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways for doing that which depends on the way you going to develop your modal (add `padding` and `margin` according to your need):

- First One : If your modal is full screen ( that is from top edge to bottom edge) **or** with margins at top and bottom and these margins are maintained when scrolling ( that top/bottom margins are not removed only modal content is scrolled )

Well you can add `position:fixed;right:someValue` property to class `.close` in this scenario and it will remain in its position with scroll too.
**Remember** to add `margin-right` for your content in modal-box so that `.close`  has a clear path to move . Well this is your wish , you can let the `.close` overlap the content. You can use `absolute` position instead of `fixed` but than place it accordingly.

- Second One : If modal is having margins at top and bottom and top margin are removed when scrolling ( that is content is scrolling with respect to top edge)

Well you can add `position:sticky;top:0;right:someValue` property to class `.close` so that it stick to the top when it is scrolled .

Showed one of the above in below snippet

**First one with margins**

```css
.ModalBlur {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #00000040;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.Modal {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 124px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top:15%;
  right: 23%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <div>This modal is different widths.
      <br>Depending on the screen.
      <br>you view it on.
      <br>It may
      <br>get so long
      <br>you have to scroll.</div>
    <div>This modal is different widths.
      <br>Depending on the screen.
      <br>you view it on.
      <br>It may
      <br>get so long
      <br>you have to scroll.</div>
    <div>This modal is different widths.
      <br>Depending on the screen.
      <br>you view it on.
      <br>It may
      <br>get so long
      <br>you have to scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ***JavaScript*** to do this with a couple of lines of code. Get the position of your modal element using ***getBoundingClientRect()*** which returns an object telling you the size and position of the element. Then you can set it in CSS using CSS variable sent via the *root*, ***HTML*** document and `rootEl.style.setProperty('--css-variable', 'property')`.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.Modal')
const close = document.querySelector('.close')
// define the getBoundingClientRect object as a variable 
// and get the top and left positions of the Modal element
const rect = modal.getBoundingClientRect()
// set root css variables for both top and 
// right positions of the closing element.
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--modal-top', `${rect.top}px`)
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--modal-right', `${rect.left + 20}px`)
```

```css
.ModalBlur {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #00000040;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.Modal {
  max-width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  /* consider a calc adding top padding and closing elements height here 
     padding: calc(16px + 32px) */
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 48px; 
  margin: 16px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 124px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.close {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--modal-top);
  right: var(--modal-right);
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModalBlur">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <div>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```